# Use LassoSelector on Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I've created a Basemap with

```
bmap = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=-80, urcrnrlat=80, llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, resolution='c')
```

Further a LassoSelector is created (the onselect function as well). However handing over the bmap to the LassoSelector like:

```
LassoSelector(bmap, onselect)
```

leads to the error:

> AttributeError: 'Basemap' object has no attribute 'figure'

The question here is:
What do I have to hand over (if not a Basemap) to the LassoSelector object, such that one can draw a lasso -around- some data points plotted -on- the Basemap?

Thank you in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.LassoSelector) of `matplotlib.widgets.LassoSelector(ax, ..)` states, the first argument,

> `ax` : [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes)
>   The parent axes for the widget.

For once, a `Basemap` is no axes, hence the error. 
Then, if you haven't defined any axes anywhere, which you might do independent of this problem, you can still get the current axes via `plt.gca()`.

```
LassoSelector(plt.gca(), ...)
```